# Multiple if statements and then else Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement, trigonometry

I'm trying to create a calculator in javascript for inverse trigonometry functions (arcsine, arccosine, arctangent) and I have it so there are checkboxes for each input so window.alert doesn't return NULL (user-friendly).
The Form:

```
<form name="inverse">
        <legend>Legend is here.</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inverse-cb1" value="sine"></input><label> sin<sup>-1</sup> ( </label><input type="text" size=5 name="sin"><label> )</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inverse-cb2" value="cosine"></input><label> cos<sup>-1</sup> ( </label><input type="text" size=5 name="cos"><label> )</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inverse-cb3" value="tangent"></input><label> tan<sup>-1</sup> ( </label><input type="text" size=5 name="tan"><label> )</label><br>
        <br><input type="button" onclick="trigI()" value="Calculate">
    </form>
```

The script:

```
function trigI(){
var sin = document.inverse.sin.value;      //sine
var cos = document.inverse.cos.value;      //cosine
var tan = document.inverse.tan.value;      //tangent

var sin1 = Math.asin(sin);      //arcsine
var cos1 = Math.acos(cos);      //arccosine
var tan1 = Math.atan(tan);      //arctangent

var sin1d = sin1 * (180/Math.PI);    //convert radians to degrees (sine)
var cos1d = cos1 * (180/Math.PI);    //convert radians to degrees (cosine)
var tan1d = tan1 * (180/Math.PI);    //convert radians to degrees (tangent)

if (isNaN(sin) || isNaN(cos) || isNaN(tan) ){
    window.alert("Please input a number.");

    return;
}

if (!document.inverse.inverse-cb1.checked){    //no sine input
    window.alert("When cos(\u2220) = " + cos + " and tan(\u2220) = " + tan + " :" + "\n\n" + "cos\u2212\u00B2(A) = " + cos1d + "\n" + "tan\u2212\u00B2(A) = " + tan1d + "\u00B0");

    return;
}

if (!document.inverse.inverse-cb2.checked){    //no cosine input
    window.alert("When sin(\u2220) = " + sin + " and tan(\u2220) = " + tan + " :" + "\n\n" + "sin\u2212\u00B2(A) = " + sin1d + "\u00B0" + "\n" + "tan\u2212\u00B2(A) = " + tan1d + "\u00B0");

    return;
}

if (!document.inverse.inverse-cb3.checked){    //no tangent input
    window.alert("When sin(\u2220) = " + sin + " and cos(\u2220) = " + cos + " :" + "\n\n" + "sin\u2212\u00B2(A) = " + sin1d + "\u00B0" + "\n" + "cos\u2212\u00B2(A) = " + cos1d + "\u00B0");

    return;
}

if (!document.inverse.inverse-cb1.checked && !document.inverse.inverse-cb2.checked){       //no sine and cosine input
    window.alert("When tan(\u2220) = " + tan + " :" + "\n\n" + "tan\u2212\u00B2(A) = " + tan1d + "\u00B0");

    return;
}

if (!document.inverse.inverse-cb2.checked && !document.inverse.inverse-cb3.checked){       //no cosine and tangent input
    window.alert("When sin(\u2220) = " + sin + " :" + "\n\n" + "sin\u2212\u00B2(A) = " + sin1d + "\u00B0");

    return;
}

if (!document.inverse.inverse-cb1.checked && !document.inverse.inverse-cb3.checked){       //no sine and tangent input
    window.alert("When cos(\u2220) = " + cos + " :" + "\n\n" + "cos\u2212\u00B2(A) = " + cos1d + "\u00B0");

    return;
}

if (!document.inverse.inverse-cb1.checked && !document.inverse.inverse-cb2.checked && !document.inverse.inverse-cb3.checked){     //no input or checked boxes
    window.alert("Please input a number or check the correct boxes.");

    return;
}

else {
    window.alert("When sin(\u2220) = " + sin + ", cos(\u2220) = " + cos + ", and tan(\u2220) = " + tan + " :" + "\n\n" + "sin\u2212\u00B2(A) = " + sin1d + "\u00B0" + "\n" + "cos\u2212\u00B2(A) = " + cos1d + "\u00B0" + "\n" + "tan\u2212\u00B2(A) = " + tan1d + "\u00B0");
    return;
}
```

}

The Question: The multiple if statements are not working so the function never returns. How can it be made to check to conditions of the input and respond in the proper way?

Comment: and the question is?  I'm too tired to read your mind....

Comment: added question onto it @ bottom

Comment: Yes, that's some code there. I like your sense of style. Good use of the negative space, and the repetition and alignment of the word "reset" is aesthetically pleasing. I'd definitely hang this on my fridge.

Comment: And that's still not a question. "It doesn't work, how can I make it work" is the king of non-questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you what to do to make it "work", since your desired result is pretty unclear, but a number of problems in your code jumped out at me as I skimmed it top to bottom. Some will still run but give results you aren't expecting, but at least one problem will cause an error and stop the function running. So:

Most of your comments are either redundant and could be removed, or could be made redundant and removed if you made your variable names more descriptive.

The statement

```
if (isNaN(document.inverse.sin.value) == true || ...)
```

could be made simpler because you've already declared a variable `sin` that is equal to `document.inverse.sin.value` and the `== true` part is redundant. Just say

```
if (isNan(sin) || isNan(cos) || isNan(tan)) {
```

All of your "reset" statements like `var sin = null;` are both wrong and pointless because (a) using `var` means you are attempting to redeclare the variables (I think JS just ignores this), so you should just say `sin = null;`, but in any case (b) they're *local* variables within your `trigI()` function so they're all about to disappear anyway when the function returns. If you are trying to clear the fields on the screen you need to say `document.inverse.sin.value = "";`, but you don't want to annoy the user by clearing *all* the fields just because *one* of them was invalid. Tell them *which* field had a problem, set focus to that field, and let them correct it themselves.

Most of your `if` statement test something like this:

```
if (document.inverse-cb1.checked == 'false'){
```

Which will never be true because you are comparing the `.checked` property that is a boolean equal to `true` or `false` with the *string* `'false'`. You need to say

```
if (document.inverse-cb1.checked == false){    // note: no quotes
// OR, even better
if (!document.inverse-cb1.checked){
```

What is `sup.sup()` supposed to do? `sup` is a variable that you've set to `-1`. `sup()` is a non-existent function that in any case you shouldn't be trying to call as a method of a number. **Fix this first,** because I think this is what is stopping the function returning.

**EDIT:** I noticed another big problem:

```
document.inverse.inverse-cb1.checked
```

You can't use the "dot" object notation for properties that don't follow the rules for JS identifier naming, and JS identifiers can't have a "-" in them. So although "inverse-cb1" is a valid property name you have to use the array-style bracket `[]` syntax to access it:

```
document.inverse["inverse-cb1"].checked
```

Or you could just remove the "-" from both the html and your JS.

Comment: Thanks nnnnnn!  I did what ou said and realized another mistake I made but it still doesn't work. Edited code is above in the main question.

Comment: See my edit. There may still be other issues, but the one I just added is definitely stopping it working.

Comment: It works now, but when I input on one field, It will show values that don't apply to what is inputted (I will try to attach a pic).  Should I use `else if(/* condition */)` instead of `if(/* condition */)` on if statements 2-8?  Thanks again!

Comment: couldn't attach pic (@nnnnnn)

Comment: There's no point to `else if` rather than `if` if your code has a `return` inside each `if`.